# Variable number of clusters in K means

Tags: postgis, postgresql, clustering

Here is my (relevant part of) the code:

```
rejected_dbscan as 
(
select * from dbscan 
where cluster_id not in (select cluster_id from filter)
)

,

kmeans as(
SELECT
  "ID", 
  ST_ClusterKMeans(rejected_dbscan."geoJson", select (count(distinct cluster_id)/20)::INTEGER from rejected_dbscan) OVER () AS cluster_id
FROM rejected_dbscan
)

select * from kmeans
```

I am getting the following error:

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"
  Position: 843
```

which is the select statement specifying a variable number of clusters. I do not want to hardcode this value, but keep it dynamic based on the code I've written.

Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ST_ClusterKMeans` expects a single integer as its 2nd parameter, but your query is giving a set, which happens to contain a single row and a single value. You must add the result of the nested `select` inside parentheses.

```sql
with src as (select 'point(1 1)'::geometry as geom)
select ST_ClusterKMeans(geom,select 1) over() from src;

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 2: select ST_ClusterKMeans(geom,select 1) over() from src;

-------

with src as (select 'point(1 1)'::geometry as geom)
select ST_ClusterKMeans(geom,(select 1)) over() from src;

 st_clusterkmeans
------------------
                0
```